# Sprite Kit coordinate weird behavior

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
SKSprintNode child1 = [[SKSprintNode alloc] init];
child1.position = CGPointMake(1,0);
[centreNode addChild:child1]
```

Suppose I can rotate 90 degree counter-clock wise (using rotate action) with *centreNode* as the centre point. Now some weird behaviors I observed:

1) After rotation, I try to get *child1*'s position, it is still **(1,0)** instead of **(0,1)**.

2) After rotation, in *didBeginContact*, I add another *child2* with position **(0, 2)** into *centreNode*, then after that in the update method of next frame, I try to get *child2*'s position, it becomes **(2,0)**(automatically rotated for me!)

3) After rotation, in one action completion block(instead of in *didBeginContact*), I add *child2* with position **(0,2)** into *centreNode*, then after that in the update method of next frame, I try to get *child2*'s position, its position is not changed, still **(0,2)**(no automatic service?)

Can someone explain this? It seems Sprit-Kit's physics engine automatically converts the coordinates somehow......

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior, position and rotation are offsets to the respective parent positions. A child's position/rotation does not change if only a parent's position/rotation changes.

Use the [sknode convert methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint:fromNode:) to convert position to a different node's coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then for 2) and 3), I think physics engine converts the coordinate system somehow in order to detect contact.

Comment: yes, physics engine internally works with a common, global coordinate system